# Application window in universal app on phone doesn't reopen after calling and completing WebAuthenticationBroker

Tags: c#, facebook, win-universal-app

I'm making my own Facebook class. When i ask for an access token it opens on phone a new window where i need to fill in my credentials.

When pressing login the application goes to screen with a list of available apps. This only happens on phone. And only when not debugging.

I assume this is caused because phone doesn't keep multiple windows open like on desktop and therefore closes it.

My question however is how to get back to my window that called the other application.

I tried to call

```
Window.Current.Activate();
```

I thought this would reopen my window, but it doesn't for some reason.

edit: variables

```
private static string _baseUrlAuth = "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth";
private static string _redirectUrl = "http://localhost:8080/";
```

Facebook.cs

```
    public static async Task<String> GetAccessToken()
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_clientId) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(_redirectUrl))
        {
            String FacebookURL = _baseUrlAuth + "?client_id=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(_clientId) + "&redirect_uri=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(_redirectUrl) + "&scope=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(_scope) + "&display=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(_displayPopup) + "&response_type=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(_responseType);
            Uri startUri = new Uri(FacebookURL);
            Uri endUri = new Uri(_redirectUrl, UriKind.Absolute);

            WebAuthenticationResult WebAuthenticationResult = await WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateAsync(WebAuthenticationOptions.None, startUri, endUri);
            if (WebAuthenticationResult.ResponseStatus == WebAuthenticationStatus.Success)
            {
                Window.Current.Activate();//first tried calling this here, but didn't work

                string responseData = WebAuthenticationResult.ResponseData.Substring(WebAuthenticationResult.ResponseData.IndexOf("access_token"));
                String[] keyValPairs = responseData.Split('&');
                for (int i = 0; i < keyValPairs.Length; i++)
                {
                    String[] splits = keyValPairs[i].Split('=');
                    switch (splits[0])
                    {
                        case "access_token":
                            AccessToken = splits[1];
                            break;
                        case "expires_in":
                            ExpiresIn = splits[1];
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return AccessToken;
    }
```

Somwhere else

```
 private void Init()
 {
     string accessToken = await Facebook.GetAccessToken();
     Window.Current.Activate();//tried calling it here as well. didn't work either.
 }
```

I find it strange that it works when debugging and otherwise it simply doesn't go back to window with the function that called it.

I hope i don't have to keep the app open on a background thread.

Is there an easy way to solve this?

Comment: Is the question not understandable or is the problem not reproducible?
Could a demo help?

Comment: I finally found the problem. There is a crash in a library and this causes the problem that it doesn't return to the app. When resolving the crash the problem was fixed.